# Disassembling SBCL functions by address rather than name

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, sbcl

One can disassemble functions in SBCL by using `disassemble`, for example:

`(print (disassemble '+))`

yields

```
; disassembly for +
; Size: 121 bytes. Origin: #x52A7BB1D                         ; +
; 1D:       4D85DB           TEST R11, R11
; 20:       7470             JEQ L5
; 22:       498B1E           MOV RBX, [R14]
; 25:       488D43F1         LEA RAX, [RBX-15]
; 29:       A801             TEST AL, 1
; 2B:       750D             JNE L0
; 2D:       3C0A             CMP AL, 10
; 2F:       7409             JEQ L0
; 31:       A80F             TEST AL, 15
; 33:       755A             JNE L4
; 35:       803829           CMP BYTE PTR [RAX], 41
; 38:       7755             JNBE L4
; 3A: L0:   488BF3           MOV RSI, RBX
; 3D:       BB02000000       MOV EBX, 2
; 42:       EB3D             JMP L2
; 44:       660F1F840000000000 NOP
; 4D:       0F1F00           NOP
; 50: L1:   48895DF8         MOV [RBP-8], RBX
; 54:       4C8975F0         MOV [RBP-16], R14
; 58:       4C895DE8         MOV [RBP-24], R11
; 5C:       488BFB           MOV RDI, RBX
; 5F:       48F7DF           NEG RDI
; 62:       498B3CBE         MOV RDI, [R14+RDI*4]
; 66:       488BD6           MOV RDX, RSI
; 69:       E8C24FF8FF       CALL #x52A00B30                  ; GENERIC-+
; 6E:       488BF2           MOV RSI, RDX
; 71:       4C8B5DE8         MOV R11, [RBP-24]
; 75:       4C8B75F0         MOV R14, [RBP-16]
; 79:       488B5DF8         MOV RBX, [RBP-8]
; 7D:       4883C302         ADD RBX, 2
; 81: L2:   4C39DB           CMP RBX, R11
; 84:       7CCA             JL L1
; 86:       488BD6           MOV RDX, RSI
; 89: L3:   488BE5           MOV RSP, RBP
; 8C:       F8               CLC
; 8D:       5D               POP RBP
; 8E:       C3               RET
; 8F: L4:   CC57             INT3 87                          ; OBJECT-NOT-NUMBER-ERROR
; 91:       0C               BYTE #X0C                        ; RBX(d)
; 92: L5:   31D2             XOR EDX, EDX
; 94:       EBF3             JMP L3
```

However, this code contains jumps to other functions, for example a call to a generic `+` operation:

`CALL #x52A00B30`

How would I disassemble the function at address `#x52A00B30`?

Obviously, `(print (disassemble #x52A00B30))` does not work...

EDIT:

After much googling, I found this [code](https://gist.github.com/oblivia-simplex/295e81cd573ba4dd14fa). In there I found a function that seems to do what I want:

```
(print (sb-disassem:disassemble-memory #x52A00B30 100))
```

Now the problem is: how do I find out how many bytes-long that function is?

Comment: I don't think you can. It's not a Lisp function object, it's just raw memory, so it doesn't know where the function ends.

Comment: You don't need to call `(print (disassemble '+))`. Just (disassemble '+) is enough. It already prints the disassembly.